# How to set ATMEGA64a-au USART speed to 115200?

Tags: c, avr, usart, baud-rate

As the title impplies, I've [ATMEGA64a-au](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/atmel-8160-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega64a-datasheet.pdf) and 12mhz crystal, I set the baud rate to 9600 by these codes:

```
#define F_CPU 12000000UL

#define FOSC 12000000 // Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1

..

void USART0_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char) (ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char) ubrr;
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    // Set frame format: 8data, 1stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1 << USBS0) | (3 << UCSZ00);

}

void USART1_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
    UBRR1H = (unsigned char) (ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR1L = (unsigned char) ubrr;
    UCSR1B = (1 << RXEN1) | (1 << TXEN1) | (1 << RXCIE1);
    // Set frame format: 8data, 1stop bit 
    UCSR1C = (1 << USBS1) | (3 << UCSZ10);
}

..

USART0_Init(MYUBRR);
USART1_Init(MYUBRR);
```

It is fine when I work with that baud rate but I've recently come a cross a 115200bd device and I need too change it to that, but when I change this line :

```
#define BAUD 115200
```

The AVR Micro controller stops communicating, and I've no idea how to fix it. is it too fast for that device or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1`

First of all there is an issue with this formula: it rounds always downwards. You need to round it to near integer, e.g. `(FOSC / 16 + BAUD / 2) / BAUD-1`

By the way why it is `FOSC` and not `F_CPU`?

Anyway, you can calculate the error when formula `FOSC/16/BAUD-1` is used:

*MYUBRR = 12000000/16/115200-1 = 5 (5.51 rounded downwards)*

Actual UART speed will be:

*F_CPU / 16 / (MYUBRR + 1) = 12000000 / 16 / (5 + 1) = 125000*

which is 8.5% higher than required. Communication with receiver-transmitter baud rate difference more than 4.5% is not possible.

But you can set **Double Speed Operation mode** *(refer to section 25.3.2 of the datasheet)*

It can be done by setting bit `U2X` bit in `UCSRA`.

In that case UART clock will be 1/8 of the CPU clock, thus allowing higher UBRR settings:

```
// divide by 8, not 16
#define MYUBRR ((FOSC / 8 + BAUD / 2) / BAUD - 1)

...

void USART0_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
    // you can just assign the value to UBRR, compiler will handle all the thighs
    UBRR0 = ubrr;
    UCSR0A = (1 << U2X0); // enable 2x mode
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    // Set frame format: 8data, 1stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1 << USBS0) | (3 << UCSZ00);
}
```

In this case `MYUBRR` value will be:

*(12000000 / 8 + 115200 / 2) / 115200 - 1 = 12*

and actual UART speed will be

*12000000 / 8 / (12 + 1) = 115384,6*

which gives you less than 0.2% error

Comment: This is the answer,thank u, but     UBRR0 = ubrr;, should be as I mentioned in the question, the compiler couldn't do the job!